# Why is my IP address changing every time I flash a new rootfs?

Tags: networking, wifi, systemd, busybox, mac-address

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi 3 system and building my own rootfs using Buildroot. At first, I was using BusyBox as the init system and when configuring the on-board wifi card using wpa_supplicant, the router always assigned the same IP address to the board, even if I rebuilt/reflashed the SD card with a new rootfs. I then switched to using systemd. Now, whenever I rebuild/reflash the SD card, the router seems to think that the device is different and assigns it an different IP address every time I reflash the rootfs, even though the MAC address has stayed the same. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Different DHCP request? Can you monitor the network to see what the DHCP session looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You are more likely to find your answer by reviewing your router than reviewing the system. By reviewing your router's web interface, you may be able to find out:

- How the DHCP lease time is. You can confirm if your DHCP leases happen to just be expiring, contributing to new IPs being assigned.
- See the MAC address of your Raspberry Pi as the router sees it. You can confirm if there's only a single MAC address appearing for your Pi or if the router sees a different MAC address each time and *that's* why a new IP address is being assigned.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that the router would remember the association between a MAC address and an IP address for a long time. There are many more MAC addresses than IP addresses, so a DHCP server has to be prepared to give out the same IP address to different clients successively. A typical server would forget about the MAC-IP association as soon as the lease expires.

The client, however, might well remember the association for a longer time. A DHCP client can request a particular IP address. The server is free to ignore this request; typically it would honor the request when the IP address is in the right range and currently unassigned. I suspect that your client is saving the lease information somewhere (`/var/lib/dhcp` would be a good place to look) and that your router typically honors the request. When you flash a new rootfs, it doesn't have this saved lease, so the router picks whatever IP address it prefers this minute.